# How to see C# Nuget Package's source code on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget

Is there any way to see a Nuget Package's source code when we choose "Go to Definition" (or F12 or CRTL+click)?
At this time, I click (CRTL+click) on some class from Nuget Package in my code and the vscode shows me an assembly summary [metadata], where I can see only docs and methods signature.
I'd like to see all the source code from this class. 
Is there some extension I need to install or I misunderstood some config?

Comment: Are you trying to look at the source for a publicly available NuGet package, or an internal NuGet package?  It's possible to include the source when you generate a NuGet package, but as Ashish Jacob mentions, source is not generally available on publicly hosted NuGet packages.

Comment: I'm trying to look for a publicly available NuGet.

Comment: I would then suggest using a decompiler to further examine the assemblies if you cannot find the public repos as Ashish mentions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can now do this with source link enabled libraries (nuget packages included).

You can have a look at these .NET blog posts from Claire:

- [Improving Debug-time Productivity with Source Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/)
- [Producing Packages with Source Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/)

> With Source Link-enabled libraries, the debugger can download the underlying source files as you step in, and you can set breakpoints/tracepoints like you would with any other source.

Comment: I think this works while in a debug session only. It would be nice if you could jump into the source when you're just editting, to peek on what a base class actually does.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains Resharper provides this functionality by decompiling source in Visual Studio. I am not aware of integrated extension for VSCode.