# API with Xamarin.Essentials: Web Authenticator how debug?

Tags: c#, .net, api, debugging

I have a question how to debug the code on the library side? I mean mainly the Xamarin.Essentials library where I use it

```
await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
```

, and I can't check what's going on inside this function and it's causing problems. A method for debugging all other libraries would also be welcome :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see C# Nuget Package's source code on Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825167/how-to-see-c-sharp-nuget-packages-source-code-on-visual-studio-code)

Comment: it works on main project, but dont in api project :/

Comment: Do you mean the code doesn't run in your API project, or you are unable to view ChallengeAsync's code behind in the API project?

Comment: I unable to view ChallengeAsync's code behind in the API project. I would like to see step by step what is happening in this function

Comment: DO you have JustMyCode enabled? If so, disable it

Comment: i work on VS mac and i check "Step into external code" like here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/ but but the effect is only on the main project and in the nested project (api) it doesn't work

Comment: I found out why this is happening. The reason is there are no pdb files, but only in the API project, they exist in the main project. Anyone know how to add or create them?